# How to add a static ip to istio ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

Does anyone have an example how to add a static ip to istio ingress?

I use AKS.

Comment: Do you mean a static ip on the load balancer that expose the istio ingress?

Comment: I can’t say for Azure in particular but generally LoadBalancer services don’t support this. Instead use external-dns to remap dns for you if things ever change. Embrace the chaos :)

Comment: yes, static ip on the load balancer.

Comment: Maybe you can make a try as the people advised [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7724#issuecomment-411342886).

Answer (score 1):

this is not supported directly in azure, but if you just expose the ingress using `type: LoadBalancer` it would get a public ip address which wouldn't really change unless you delete the load balancer (so all the services in kubernetes).

Comment: I am trying to configure the "type: LoadBalancer" and there is also an IP option in the values.yaml for istio, but unfortunately it gives me an erro when I try to install the configurations, even the default ones:  >> Error: render error in "gateways/templates/serviceaccount.yaml": template: gateways/templates/serviceaccount.yaml:6:8: executing "gateways/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" at <$.Values.global.imagePullSecrets>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.imagePullSecrets

Comment: I got a resolution to this one. I am going to try to see if I can get the static ip working tomorrow morning.

Comment: I did try to add the loadBalancerIP and type: LoadBalancer. But these don't work. I quite concerned going in production without a static ip. Any other idea?

Comment: read the answer, please. technically you can switch ip type to static manually after it was created by k8s